# receiving Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). after implementing redux into my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

Receiving this error. Invariant Violation:

> Failed to call into JavaScript module method
> AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as
> callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace,
> JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog,
> RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter,
> GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient,
> RCTEventEmitter.

A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
This error came about after implementing redux. Redux was working, nothing was changed and then all the sudden I ran the app and this error appeared.

```
import {createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import PrEnteryScreen from './Screens/PrEnteryScreen'
import LogBookScreen from './Screens/LogBookScreen';
import AuthScreen from './Screens/AuthScreen';
import SelectExerciseModal from './Screens/SelectExerciseModal';
import RegisterModalScreen from './Screens/RegisterModalScreen';
import ExerciseInformationScreen from './Screens/ExerciseInformation';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer 
    > 
      <MainStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
        initialRouteName='AuthScreen'
        > 
          <MainStack.Group>
        
          <MainStack.Screen name = "AuthScreen" component={AuthScreen}/>        
            <MainStack.Screen name = "Home" component={Home}/>        
            <MainStack.Screen name = "PrEnteryScreen" component = {PrEnteryScreen}/>
            <MainStack.Screen name = "LogBookScreen" component={LogBookScreen}/>
            <MainStack.Screen name = "ExerciseInformationScreen" component={ExerciseInformationScreen}/>
          </MainStack.Group>
          <MainStack.Group screenOptions={{presentation: 'modal'}}>
          <MainStack.Screen name ="RegisterModalScreen" component={RegisterModalScreen}/>
            <MainStack.Screen name ="SelectExerciseModal" component={SelectExerciseModal} />
          </MainStack.Group>
      </MainStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PrApp', () => App);


export default App;
```

I added `AppRegistry.registerComponent('PrApp', () => App);` to try and solve the problem but it doesn't work. When I restart from before implementing redux the app works.

Comment: what version of **react native** you ar using ?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest **react native version** (greater than 0.70). there are many changes and it seems some packages are not supported.  just downgrade `react native to >0.69` until they fix it .